# Redis & MySQL - When should I use redis on its own VS when to use it working together with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, redis

I'm new to redis and I have used MySQL to store data before.

From what I've learned and know, I have concluded that there are possibly two modes for the two database to work. One is "cooperating" mode between redis and MySQL (it's a little difficult to explain so I drew a diagram):

[image: write data into database]

[image: read data from database]

The other is a mode only using redis' database:

[image: only redis]

Or only MySQL, which I have done before.

So, I was wondering when to combine the two kinds of databases to work together, and when to separate them to let them to do their jobs individually and carry out their own functions?

I would be grateful if you can illustrate with an example.

Comment: Answers will be matters of opinion. Sorry to say, that doesn't fit well with the Stack Overflow format. Redis is often used as a cache for persistent data in MySQL, as shown in your second example.

Answer (score 5):

Every application is different but in general I use MySQL for persistent data, that may grow large over time.  Redis is an in-memory data store so how much data you can store in it is limited by how much RAM it has.  Redis makes an excellent cache, for example for storing data to avoid looking it up from MySQL frequently.

It is common to use both - MySQL as the main database backend and Redis as a helper cache for speed, to keep counts of popular pages and that sort of thing.  This was a vague answer to a vague question but I hope it helps!